# Does selenium not support CSS3 Selectors?

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

Not that I am master of CSS Selector but got to know that following is the CSS 3 selector -

```
css=li:nth-child(1) div[class=team-name]
```

While following is CSS 2 selector -

```
css=li:first-child div[class=team-name]
```

When I use the CSS 2 selector for -

```
Selenium.getText("cssSelector")
```

I get the correct text but using CSS 3 selector throws exception stating -

```
Element css=li:nth-child(1) div[class=team-name] a not found
```

If it were only this I would probably use CSS 2 selector. But I need to iterate through couple of links and read text, i.e -

```
for(int i=1; i<loopCount; i++) {
        ArrayList.add(selenium.getText("css=li:nth-child("+i+") div[class=team-name] a"));
}
```

Now how would this be possible if I were to use CSS 2 selector.

Comment: You really don't need to promote the proposal in every other Selenium question you ask.

Answer (score 1):

When using nth-child for CSS3 selector in selenium, somehow selenium truncates the sting after it so it is only referring to `Element css=li:nth-child(1)`. As a workaround use,

```
Element css=li:nth-child(1) > div[class=team-name]
```

'>' makes all the  difference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: using ">" would mark it direct child which is not the case with my scenario

Comment: I suppose it indicates - http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2011/01/why-jquery-in-selenium-css-locators-is-the-way-to-go/ that selenium 1.0 does not have this capability

Comment: Even I struggled with it a lot, right now I use different loops for each type of element that I want to locate after nth-child() as > gives direct descendant only. I guess, Xpath would be more suitable in this case.