# “:nth-of-type() or nth-child()” Selector work for IE 9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, selenium-webdriver

I have updated to IE 9. I am using Selenium version 2.31.2.0

According to this site, IE 9 should support the `:nth-of-type()` selector. However, I appear to be getting a NullPointerException.

Any help?

Comment: Yes, IE9 should do. I'd do a few things: check to make sure the page is not being rendered in a weird 'browser emulation' mode - verify this by opening the IE Developer Tools and ensure it's set to display in "IE9 Standards Mode". I'd also post a small snippet of the code you are using, where the error occurs and the full stack trace of that error. Also, I noticed your other question about CSS selectors in IE9 which I answered. Use my answer to run the query in IE9, see what IE brings back (screenshot it if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

It does work with CSS3-Pseudoselectors.-> See [Does selenium not support CSS3 Selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794456/does-selenium-not-support-css3-selectors)

Please show the specific code